# java 8 how to use collection streams to check for presence of an object

Tags: collections, java-8

I'm new to java 8 programming and would like to know what is the best way to rewrite the below using streams()/lambda's.

```
class Person {
  String name;
  int age;
  ...
}

public boolean checkPersonAboveAge(List<Person> persons, int age) {
    for (Person person : persons) {
       if (person.age > age) {
          return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So far i tried:

```
public boolean checkPersonAboveAge(List<Person> persons, int age) {
    Person p = persons.stream().filter(p -> p.age > age).findAny().orElse(null);
    if (p != null) {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I read that with lamdba's the readability of code would improve, but looking at this example either i'm not using this feature right or missing something.

Comment: You really are interested in "what is the **best** way", then I'll have to close your question as potentially attracting opinion-driven answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your current stream attempt does indeed work, but it's an uncommon and not the best way to go about it.

1. You create an Optional object that you immediately throw away.
2. The code is not as compact as it can be.

Instead, utilise the [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) method which does exactly what you're trying to achieve.

```
return persons.stream().anyMatch(p -> p.age > age);
```

Comment: Awesome! exactly what i was looking for. Thanks